# On Gazebo Sim "gz-garden" install, how to correct ros_gz Compile Errors for ros_gz_project_template "diff_drive example

Tags: simulation, gazebo, ros-humble

"How to install ros_gz Garden from Source" on a Ubuntu 22.04 arm64/aarch64 Jammy/ROS 2 Humble machine that has a working "gz-garden".

April 25, 2023. I'm discontinuing this work to get Gazebo Sim gz-garden & ros_gz working together, and restarting with a clean ROS2 Humble Desktop (with included Fortress Simulation), installing from Binary an Ignition Fortress and ros_gz, (which I have just completed which works) and then a new compile of the ros_gz_project_template over the Ignition Gazebo.

April 15, 2023
I followed this advice to install ros_gz from source:

On my Ubuntu 22.04/ROS 2 Desktop Full (Machine is MAC M1 Virtual Machine arm64/aarch64), removed ros-ign-* from the Desktop Full Install and my previous Binary installed sudo apt install ros-humble-gz-garden . Previously installed gz-garden as described here: https://staging.gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu .

This works: Run $ gz sim shapes.sdf .

So I attempted a source install from https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz into ~: ws/ workspace
Set the GZ_VERSION environment variable to the Gazebo version you'd like to compile against. For example:

export GZ_VERSION=garden
To enable the $ rosdep command to successfully complete, I followed "Known Issue of Command Line Tools, https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-transport.

I configured the environment variable GZ_CONFIG_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.gz/tools/config/ directory that contains links to the known location of python gz-sim7, gz-math7 and transport12. This directory contains gz and libgz-transport12.so.12.1.0 folders containing links created by the link commands:
$ ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gz/math7.cpython-310-aarch64-linux-gnu.so, 
$ ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gz/sim7.cpython-310-aarch64-linux-gnu.so, and
$ ln -s /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgz-transport12.so.12.1.0

#Setup Workspace ~:$ /ws

git clone https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz.git -b humble

NOTE: I changed the ROS2 branch to humble.

~: ws $ rosdep install -r --from-paths src -i -y --rosdistro humble

~/ws$ rosdep install -r --from-paths src -i -y --rosdistro humble 
-: $ #All required rosdeps installed successfully

/ws
colcon build

Compile Error results::

ros_gz_sim, ros_ign_gazebo, ros_ign_sim,  ros_gz_interfaces finished, while the next os_gz_bridge continued for 5 mins then exited code 2 with several 100 error messages.

1 Package failed: ros_gz_bridge
1 package had stderr output: ros_gz_bridge
7 packages not processed.

Suggested next steps?

Comment: If you code format the relevant parts of your post, it would make it a lot easier to read. The easier it is to read, the more likely you are to get an answer. I vaguely remember previously attempting to format this text when you posted it as an answer to another question. Maybe take a look at that edit that I made, and apply it here. Also, please include the link from whence this advice, that you followed, came.

Comment: Tnx for response & sry for long post. The reason to compile ros_gz to work with gz garden is that ros_gz Binary install is Fortress. https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz . This https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim suggests a GZ_CONFIG_PATH parameter to workaround a Known issue of Command tools. If this is correct logic, I am unsure how to configure a ln to point to the installed python3-gzsim7, python3-gxmath7, gz-transport12 libraries.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add any new info there, and not in the comments.

Comment: Have you tried following these instructions https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/ros_installation? There are specific [instructions](https://github.com/osrf/osrf-rosdep#installing-rosdep-rules-to-resolve-gazebo-garden-libraries) there for using `rosdep`

Comment: Yes, but installing ros_gz Garden must be done from Source, which is the problem described above. Did the rosdep rules resolve procedure which completed clean. However, there is no package ros-humble-ros-gzgarden-* in either arm64 http-//packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-arm64/Packages or amd64 repository, just gz-fortress and ros-humble-ros-gz that is Fortress as its dependancies listed are version "11". Also https://github.com/osrf/osrf-rosdep/blob/master/gz/gazebo.yaml only lists gz-garden and other dependancies.